# Session variables lost on new page

Tags: php, security, session, web

I'm currently developing a web application for a client with the webspace hosted on one.com.

I've implemented my own secure login system and everything works. When I log someone in, the variables are available but as soon as I go to a new page via an href all my session variables are lost. I've tried almost everything that is recommended on similar questions but it won't work.

I can not edit my php.ini directly, this is the standard phpinfo:

[I can't embed Images yet, this is my phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJgRe.png)

Additionally at the beginning of every site I call

```
 ini_set("session.cookie_secure", 0);
```

Because at the beginning this was (locally) always set to true.

I initiate a secure session on every page with the following code:

```
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
$secure = true;
// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session$id.
$httponly = true;
// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}
// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 

    $secure,
    $httponly);
// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

I just dont understand why my Session variables are always lost. I would be happy about every help I can get!

**Edit:** Some suggestd that the last line:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Propably causes the problem but after removing it it still doesn't work. What else could it be?

Comment: Umm… `session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.` … and you say your session data is deleted each time?

Comment: I thought this call only deletes older, vulnerable variables. Is it not like this?

Comment: Is the session cookie safely received from the sever and send back?

Comment: How do I check for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this line (the bottom line) is the one destroying the session:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);  // regenerated the session, delete the old one
```

Remove that line and your session should be retrained.

Comment: I thought this call only deletes older, vulnerable variables. Is it not like this?

Comment: When removing the line the same is still happening. What else could it be?